react native Stopwatch : restart immediatly after a stop
I have a stopwatch running. I need to stop and restart from 0 immediatly when the user click a button. It's working if the user click Stop and then click a Start button. But when I try to do that in one operation, the timer is reset to 0 and then continue with the previous count. I guess this is due to asynchrone behavior in setTime state. Is anyone have an idea on how to get the behavior I need? Thanks!
Here a code of a stopwatch...
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  // State and refs to manage time and stopwatch status
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);
  const startTimeRef = useRef(0);

  // *****Function to start the stopwatch***************************
  const startStopwatch = () => {
    if (running) {
      resetStopwatch();
    }

    startTimeRef.current = Date.now() - time * 1000;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(Math.floor((Date.now() - startTimeRef.current) / 1000));
    }, 1000);
    setRunning(true);
  };

  // ******Function to pause the stopwatch**************************
  const pauseStopwatch = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    setRunning(false);
  };

  // *****Function to reset the stopwatch***************************
  const resetStopwatch = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    setTime(0);
    setRunning(false);
  };

  // *****Function to resume the stopwatch*************************
  const resumeStopwatch = () => {
    startTimeRef.current = Date.now() - time * 1000;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(Math.floor((Date.now() - startTimeRef.current) / 1000));
    }, 1000);
    setRunning(true);
  };

  /************************************************************* */
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Geeksforgeeks</Text>
      <Text style={styles.subHeader}>Stop Watch In Native</Text>
      <Text style={styles.timeText}>{time}s</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.pauseButton]} onPress={pauseStopwatch}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pause</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.startButton]} onPress={startStopwatch}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.resetButton]} onPress={resetStopwatch}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </>

        {!running && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.resumeButton]} onPress={resumeStopwatch}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Resume</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

/************************************************************************************ */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "green",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  subHeader: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: "blue",
  },
  timeText: {
    fontSize: 48,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  button: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  startButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#2ecc71",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  resetButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#e74c3c",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  pauseButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#f39c12",
  },
  resumeButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#3498db",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;

What I need:

Click Start. This start the stopwatch
Click Start again. This must restart the stopwatch to 0. (the UI is not done of course... the code is just for testing)

